# Is there a specific flatshare site covering Scotland?

Tags: online-resources, accommodation, rental, scotland

I move around often enough while still needing to find regular accommodation as I travel.  I've found that different countries focus on different flatshare sites, mostly because the multilingual ones like easyroomates cost money.  I'm specifically looking for accommodation options in St. Andrews in Scotland, which appears too small for flatshare.com, which usually had the best options for Manchester. Many other such sites don't cover Scotland or have very few listings available.

Is there a specific flatshare site for Scotland? I'd be particularly interested in sites that cater to non-anglophone foreigners living in Britain.

Comment: Hi Jeff, currently this isn't exactly a travel question - we try to steer clear of housing/immigration questions.  Could you perhaps reword to make more travel related? For suggestions, see the [faq].  Cheers.

Comment: I move to different countries so often that I forget it might not be considered travel.  lol  I'll check out the faq.

Comment: Yeah, I was sorta on the fence on this one, as it's something I do as well.  I'll edit it as well just to tweak a bit, let me know if it has changed your intention.

Comment: you're probably aware of trendy "airbnb" which has spring up in the meantime.  holiday-rentals.co.uk is biggest for "holiday accoms" as such.

Answer (score 8):

The definitive, free site for flatsharing in London, at least, is [Gumtree](http://www.gumtree.com/).  It also covers the rest of the UK, including Scotland.

Comment: My experience of the Rest of the UK is that Spareroom is considerably more used (and less full of scams), although Gumtree is functional.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [spareroom](http://www.spareroom.co.uk/) (although spare room costs if you want access to adds straight away) London focused but it does have adds for the rest of the country.